# Matlab - plot bar and line graph on the same y axis

Tags: matlab, plot, line

I'm trying to plot a line graph and a bar graph on the same y-axis:

```
figure; 
plotyy(Pert, Rfootvel(:,i+1), Pert, 0,'bar','plot');
hold(ax(1), 'on');
legend('Pert 1-8', 'Base');
ylim(ax(2), [0 1]);
title(['The avg pert velocity of the first step vs the avg base velocity, PP' num2str(j)]);
```

Unfortunately, setting the second y-axis limit like this doesn't affect the second y-axis. Matlab simply does what it thinks is best. However, I need to directly compare the two, so the axes need to be the same. Can anyone help here?

Comment: Don't you miss an output argument to `plotyy` ? Maybe you forgot to show it in your snippet. eg `[ax,BarPlot,RegPlot] = plotyy(...)`

Comment: Maybe you're looking for [`linkaxes`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linkaxes.html)?

Comment: @Benoit_11, that turned out to be the problem. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Great! Do you mind if I write that as an answer so that the thread is closed for future reference?

Comment: @Benoit_11 no not at all

Comment: Alright I just did. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use `ax(n)` you need to provide [plotyy](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plotyy.html) with the right output arguments. In your case, you could use the following:

```
figure; 

%// Here BarPlot and RegPlot are not really needed so you could replace them with ~.

[ax,BarPlot,RegPlot] = plotyy(Pert, Rfootvel(:,i+1), Pert, 0,'bar','plot');

hold(ax(1), 'on');

legend('Pert 1-8', 'Base');
ylim(ax(2), [0 1]);
title(['The avg pert velocity of the first step vs the avg base velocity, PP' num2str(j)]);
```